# software center not showing openmpi and other essential packages

Tags: 14.04, software-center

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. But in the Software Center `openmpi`, `scalapack`, `libblas` etc. are not being shown. What is the cause ?

Comment: I had the impression that the software center is showing mostly (gui based) applications but no libraries. thats why I usually fall back to command line tools for package management even on desktop systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it via the command line.  Need to open terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, and there you just:

> sudo apt-get install openmpi-common

You can do the same for any other library package.  As indicated in one of the comments, libraries not always show in the Ubuntu Software Center (USC).

If you prefer to use a GUI you can always install `synaptic` through the USC and then just use that to install the packages.